# Symfony 5 - Login with json_login; Login process is not working;

Tags: php, json, ajax, symfony, authentication

first of all I want to let you know, that I'm new to Symfony.
I'm on my way to move my PHP project from my own "basic" MVC to Symfony. The project is already running and working well, but I have some issues with adjusting to Symfony.

I started with the basic skeleton, make:user and make:auth. The template worked well.
But I failed converting the login process to AJAX and JSON.

I followed this official tutorial: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform-security/json-login as well as https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/json_login_setup.html

This is my security.yaml

```
security:
encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: auto

# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: true
        lazy: true
        provider: app_user_provider

        json_login:
            check_path: app_login
            username_path: email
            password_path: password
            
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\UserAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: app_logout
            # where to redirect after logout
            target: home
```

This is my Controller:

```
class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    // methods={"POST"}

    /**
     * @Route("/api/login", name="app_login")
     */
    public function login(Request $request): Response
    {
        return $this->json([
            'user' => $this->getUser() ? $this->getUser()->getId(): null,
            'error' => 1,
            'content' => $request->getMethod()
            ]);
    }
```

I removed "methods={"POST"}" because of the Problem with the request method.

First problem

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login -d '{"email": "test@test.de", "password": "1234"}
```

returns

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='/api/login'" />

        <title>Redirecting to /api/login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="/api/login">/api/login</a>.
    </body>
</html>
```

content returns always "GET"

```
'content' => $request->getMethod()
```

user returns always NULL
'user' => $this->getUser() ? $this->getUser()->getId(): null,

Server Terminal Output:

```
[PHP        ] [Thu Mar 25 16:05:13 2021] 127.0.0.1:60846 [302]: POST /api/login
[PHP        ] [Thu Mar 25 16:05:13 2021] 127.0.0.1:60846 Closing
[PHP        ] [Thu Mar 25 16:05:13 2021] 127.0.0.1:60848 Accepted
[PHP        ] [Thu Mar 25 16:05:13 2021] [info] Matched route "app_login".
[PHP        ] 
[PHP        ] [Thu Mar 25 16:05:13 2021] [debug] Checking for guard authentication credentials.
[PHP        ] 
[PHP        ] [Thu Mar 25 16:05:13 2021] [debug] Checking support on guard authenticator.
[PHP        ] 
[PHP        ] [Thu Mar 25 16:05:13 2021] [debug] Guard authenticator does not support the request.
```

Where is my mistake?

EDIT: Added UserAuthenticator.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\PasswordAuthenticatedInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class UserAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator implements PasswordAuthenticatedInterface
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'email' => $request->request->get('email'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['email']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Email could not be found.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
    }

    /**
     * Used to upgrade (rehash) the user's password automatically over time.
     */
    public function getPassword($credentials): ?string
    {
        return $credentials['password'];
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $providerKey)
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('home'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your UserAuthenticator as well? It looks like your supports method does not work properly, but just to be safe add the whole file in case the problem is in another stage of the login process

Comment: Thanks to you I modified

public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

to:

public const LOGIN_ROUTE = '';

Now everything is working. But I can't understand why this solved the problem. Maybe you can tell me. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that your Authenticator is used right now and not another one? If you have the profiler-pack installed then your response should contain a special header with a profiler url in it. When you open that in the browser you get debug information for that request & response. Please go there and check the security tab for details

Comment: I don't understand why an empty route would "fix" it. Maybe you can also check `php bin/console debug:router` and see if your `app_login` route appears and matches the path you expect. Maybe there is some weird path override going on

Comment: Security Token

`Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken {#561 ▼
  -credentials: null
  -firewallName: "main"
  -user: App\Entity\User {#452 …}
  -roleNames: [▶]
  -authenticated: true
  -attributes: []
}`

Configuration

`provider  security.user.provider.concrete.app_user_provider
context  main
entry_point  App\Security\UserAuthenticator
user_checker  security.user_checker
access_denied_handler  (none)
access_denied_url  (none)
listeners  

[▼
  "guard"
  "json_login"
  "anonymous"
]`

Comment: I changed the route name back to "app_login" and the debug:router remains the same and correct:

`app_login POST ANY ANY /api/login`

But after changing back to "app_login"

=> No route found for "GET /api/login": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)

Debug -> Security -> Entry Point: entry_point  App\Security\UserAuthenticator

Comment: Could it be that you redirect to the login url with a get request at some point? Your Authenticator extends AbstractFormAuthenticator which is primarily for login forms. When you use them, each time you are not authenticated you will first be redirected via GET to the login url. It looks like at some point this happening, I am just not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

In the **UserAuthenticator.php** I modified the line

```
public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';
```

to

```
public const LOGIN_ROUTE = '';
```

It solved the problem with the Request Method as well as the Login procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and your solution help, but the symfony will make a lot of redirect (check your console), my solution  was to implement the method

```
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
          return null;
    }
```

and also the method

```
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $providerKey)
    {
            return null;
    }
```

Very important, if an user try to acces any restricted route the symfony will redirect the user to de login page, (in your case login page  will contain a json response, not so friendly for the user)

my solution was to implement method start and make a redirect to homepage

`public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
{
   return new RedirectResponse("/");
}`

My final class:

`namespace App\Security;
    
    use App\Entity\User;
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\PasswordAuthenticatedInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;
    
    class AppCustomAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator implements PasswordAuthenticatedInterface
    {
        use TargetPathTrait;
    
        public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';
    
        private $entityManager;
        private $urlGenerator;
        private $csrfTokenManager;
        private $passwordEncoder;
    
        public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
        {
            $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
            $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
            $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
            $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
        }
    
        public function supports(Request $request)
        {
            return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route')
                && $request->isMethod('POST');
        }
    
        public function getCredentials(Request $request)
        {
            $credentials = [
                'email' => $request->request->get('email'),
                'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
                'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
            ];
            $request->getSession()->set(
                Security::LAST_USERNAME,
                $credentials['email']
            );
    
            return $credentials;
        }
    
        public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
        {
            $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
    
            if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
                throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
            }
    
            $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);
    
            if (!$user) {
                // fail authentication with a custom error
                throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Email could not be found.');
            }
    
            return $user;
        }
    
        public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
        {
            return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
        }
    
        /**
         * Used to upgrade (rehash) the user's password automatically over time.
         */
        public function getPassword($credentials): ?string
        {
            return $credentials['password'];
        }
    
        public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $providerKey)
        {
            return null;
        }
    
        protected function getLoginUrl()
        {
            return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
        }
    
        public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    
        public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
        {
            return new RedirectResponse("/");
        }
    }`

p.s I know is an old post, but i hope my post help someone.