# Symfony 6 json_login don't authenticate user

Tags: json, authentication, symfony, symfony6

I have running a simple symfony/skeleton.

Basically I followed the documentation on "json_login", however Symfony does not authenticate the user when the login route is called. I test via Thunder Client in VSC.

I can call the /login route method, but the user object is basically NULL. In the meantime I have also tried to use my own authenticator, however this has not brought me any further in all variations. I have first tested with Symfony 6.1.*, last on version 6.2.*.

I would be very grateful for a tip or a link to a working tutorial. Thanks

I have already created a user entity via make:user which has the following structure:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 180, unique: true)]
    private ?string $email = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private array $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     */
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?string $password = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }
}
```

Then I created a controller for the /login and /logout routes with the following structure:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Attribute\CurrentUser;

class UserLoginController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/login', name: 'app_login')]
    public function index(#[CurrentUser] ?User $user): Response
    {
        if (null === $user) {
            return $this->json([
                'message' => 'missing credentials',
            ], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        return $this->json([
            'message' => 'Welcome to your new controller!',
            'path' => 'src/Controller/ApiLoginController.php',
            'user' => $user->getUserIdentifier()
        ]);
    }
}
```

And my configuration for it looks like this:

```
security:
  password_hashers:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: "auto"
  providers:
    app_user_provider:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\User
        property: email
  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    main:
      json_login:
        check_path: /app_login
        username_path: email
        password_path: password
      lazy: true
      provider: app_user_provider
      #custom_authenticator: App\Security\UserAuthenticator

  access_control:
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: hello look here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66802330/symfony-5-login-with-json-login-login-process-is-not-working
and check php bin/console debug:router

Comment: @kubarik debug:router indicates that the route exists. the controller gives me "missing credentials" back, thats not my point. My problem is that the user is not authenticated although he runs the correct method to the route.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).